# Wikipedia search API get redirect pageID

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I get many Wikipedia pageIDs in DB, and some of them are already redirected to somewhere else.

So I want to know how to get these new pageIDs.

I check the Wikipedia web:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/?curid=11601783
```

It says (Redirected from....) which means it is not the main link I want. The good link should be:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/?curid=34344124
```

So I want to know how to get the final pageID by API search like:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=extracts&pageids=11601783
```

What parameters should I use?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To make the API resolve redirects, just add `redirects` to a query. So, for example:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&pageids=11601783&redirects

will give you the page id of the redirect target.

There doesn't seem to be a good way to do this using a single query for multiple pages, because the `redirects` part of the response maps from title to title, not page id (I'm assuming you don't know the title of the redirect page).

One way to work around that would be to combine `redirects` with `prop=redirects`:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&pageids=11601783&redirects&prop=redirects&rdlimit=max

This will give you all redirects to the target page, including their page ids.